# Flutter: comparison operators

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, operators

I'm trying to validate a form with a comparison operator but it's giving me this error.

```
The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try defining the operator '>'
```

```dart
    String fare = ''; //the value I want
    double amount = totalDistance * 0.25; //code for total distance has already been taken care of
        String amountPerPass = amount.toStringAsFixed(0);
        setState(() {
          fare = amountPerPass;
        });
```

This works well and i get the `fare`.
However, I wan to use the `fare` to validate a form. But it's not working. Any help?

```
TextFormField(
validator: (value) 
{if (value!.isEmpty) 
{return ('Enter the amount per passenger');}
if (value > fare) //The error occurs here with the operator sign. How can I correct it?
{   
return ('Your price should not exceed $fare');
}
},
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, use  `fare` as double dataType(or another variable based on your need) to compare on if state.

```dart
 double fare = totalDistance * 0.25;  
....
TextFormField(
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return ('Enter the amount per passenger');
    }
    final current = double.tryParse("${value}") ?? 0;
    if (current > fare) {
      return ('Your price should not exceed $fare');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` in `TextFormField.validator` is of type `String?`. You should firstly check it for nullability, and then you can do [`double.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.4/dart-core/double/tryParse.html) or [`int.tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.4/dart-core/int/tryParse.html), depending on whether you accept a floating point.

This will return one of the numeric types or null if the string wasn't valid.

Be aware though, that if you decide to accept a floating point value, different languages use different formatting and use different characters for thousand separator and decimal separator.

Comment: I'm no expert i programming. Could you help me implement the int.tryParse to the code. Don't know how to do it. I checked the link but don't how to implement it to my code